# getline function doesn't seem to be working in c++

Tags: c++, file

```cpp
ifstream read;
read.open(name);
char g[3];
read.getline(g,3);
char v = read.get();
cout << v;
read.close();
```

the issue i'm having is that after the getline function, the get is set to garbage and the file doesn't read properly anymore. However im sure that the file im reading contains  more characters than getline takes, so what is issue?

Comment: See some examples of how [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is used.

Comment: Just because you see a value as "garbage" does not mean the value has no value. Especially since [`istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) returns an `int` that you then store in a `char`. What is the output you see? What value gets streamed if you cast `v` to `int` when streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the read worked?

When you use a read always check the read worked before using the value:

```
if (read.getline(g,3)) {
    // Read worked correctly 
    std::cout << "Got: >" << std::string(g, read.gcount()) << "<\n";
}
else {
    std::cerr << "Read Failed\n";
    throw "Failed";
}

if ((v = read.get()) != EOF) {
    std::cout << "Got: >" << v << "<\n";
}
else {
    std::cerr << "Read Failed\n";
    throw "Failed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read file by `std::fstream`:

```
std::string str;
std::fstream file = "test.txt";//write in text.txt: GhY67. Test.

while(getline(file, str))//while get line of test.txt file, 
 // saves 
//    line in str string.
{
     std::cout << str << '\n';
    //Outputs str string(all lines in test.txt document)
}
```

If your wish always input characters, write this code:

```
std::string str;
while(getline(std::cin, str))//while getline in console, user 
//inputs characters and characters in onr line saves in str 
//string.*
{
     if(str == "What?")
     {
          std::cout << "Hello, world!";
         //*If user inputs string "What?", console outputs 
         string "Hello, world!*/
      }
 }
```